# ReactJS. action is successfully dispatched but not reaching reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the componentDidMount() method, i dispatched an async action that fetch some data from another API. In the redux dev tool, the fetch data success method is dispatched, and it has the right payload retrieved from response. However, this action did not seem to reach the reducer, as the state in my redux store was unchanged. I injected console.log() in my reducer and noticed that the reducer was not reached.

I viewed other relevant posts but i cant find any solutions.

I have provided the relevant code snippets and will appreciate any help! i am using thunk as the middleware.

```
//index.js

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  search: searchBarReducer,
});

const composeEnhancers = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ : null || compose;

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();

//action creator 

export const suggestionsInit = (filter) => {
  console.log("[suggestionsInit]")
  return (dispatch) => {
    let result = [];
    axios
      .get("")
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.forEach((element) => {
          result.push(element.moduleCode);
        });
        dispatch(fetchSuggestionsSuccess(result));
      })
      //
  };
};

export const fetchSuggestionsSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS,
    data: data,
  };
};

//reducer

const initialState = {
    modules: [],
    //
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SEARCHBAR_INT: 
        return {
            ...state,
            modules: action.data
        }
        default: return state;
    }
}

//associated component

componentDidMount() {
    console.log("[componentDidMount]");
    this.props.dispatchSuggestionsInit("modules");
  }

...
//after class body 

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    modules: state.search.modules,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatchSuggestionsInit: (filter) => dispatch(actions.suggestionsInit(filter)),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withErrorHandler(SearchBar, axios));
//with error handler is just another higher order component and it does not affect the functionality.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you reducer file you should be listening/checking for the success case of dispatch, reason being you when you dispatch the success data the action you are dispatching with action type of `actionTypes.FETCH_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS` and not INIT one.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.FETCH_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        modules: action.data
      };
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: apologies, i realized that i left out the other switch case while simplifying the content i copied over here. The problem was that in my initial code i used the || operator in the switch case as i wanted FETCH_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS and INT to perform the same operation. However, i was unaware that this was not supported in switch statements. The problem is resolved. Thanks a lot for your help!!